# SignalR client method not triggered due to parameter type

Tags: signalr, parameter-passing

I have the following SignalR problem:

Server code:

```
public class ConnectionHandlerModel
{
    public static Collection<ConnectedDigiModel> Digis = new Collection<ConnectedDigiModel>();
}

public class ConnectedDigiModel
{
    public string ConnectionID = "";
    public string DeviceNr = "";
    public string GroupName = "";
    public string UserName = "";

    public ConnectedDigiModel(string ConnectionID, string username)
    {
        this.ConnectionID = ConnectionID;
        this.UserName = username;
    }
}

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var username = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["username"];
    ConnectionHandlerModel.Digis.Add(new ConnectedDigiModel(Context.ConnectionId, username));
}

public async Task SendConnectedDigis()
{
    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ConnectedDigisToSTM", ConnectionHandlerModel.Digis);
}
```

Client code:

```
private async void btnGetConnectedDigis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await digiConnection.InvokeAsync("SendConnectedDigis");
}

digiConnection.On<Collection<ConnectedDigiModel>>("ConnectedDigisToSTM", (digis) =>
{
    foreach (ConnectedDigiModel digi in digis)
    {
        listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { listBox1.Items.Add(digi.UserName.ToString()); }));
    }
});
```

Problem:
The last method is not triggered.

I changed it to sending just a string and it works. Why is the collection as parameter preventing the methods execution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Seems like the class you use as parameter for signalr has to have the setters and getters.

This works:

```
public class ConnectedDigiModel {
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceNr { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ConnectedDigiModel(string ConnectionID, string username)
    {
        this.ConnectionID = ConnectionID;
        this.UserName = username;
    } }
```